# Powershell script : Service now

Tags: powershell, servicenow

I have got the response from the service now api

```
enter code here

$geturl = $ParentURL + "/table/sc_req_item?
```

sysparm_query=number="+$RITMNumber+"&sysparm_display_value=all&sysparm_fields=number,short_description,requested_for.first_name,requested_for.last_name,requested_for.user_name"

```
number                   : @{display_value=RITM2519394; value=RITMXXXX}
short_description        : @{display_value=Login As ABC xyz on 19 Feb. Creating ticket for tracking purposes.; value=Login As ABC xyz on 19 Feb. Creating ticket for tracking purposes.}
requested_for.first_name : @{display_value=abc; value=abc}
requested_for.user_name  : @{display_value=Exxxx; value=Exxxx}
requested_for.last_name  : @{display_value=xyz; value=xyz}
```

I am able to display get the short description using $ShortDescription = $($response.result.short_description.value)

Login As ABC xyz on 19 Feb. Creating ticket for tracking purposes.

But when I m trying to get the requested for first name and last name I m getting blank

$RequestFor = $($response.result.requested_for.first_name)

could you please help me in sorting out

Comment: PowerShell has a list of reserved variables, characters (the dot is one of them), etc., and if anything you are using has them, then you must escape them or properly quote, stringafy them. Extra dots, spaces, etc, are just self-inflicted problems one should completely avoid.

Comment: Just quote it: `$response.result."requested_for.first_name"`. (If an identifier also contains quotes, these can be escaped: ``"escaped `"quote"``. And to escape the backtick, of course, use another one: ``"this is a ```"bad idea`""``.